# Error when execute UPDATE with inherit target and inherited source table in GridDB

Tags: griddb

This error occurs when I execute `UPDATE` with inherit target and inherited source table. The scenario is as follows:

```
create table foo (f1 int, f2 int);
create foreign table foo2 (f3 int) inherits (foo)
  server griddb_svr options (table_name 'loct1');
create table bar (f1 int, f2 int);
create foreign table bar2 (f3 int) inherits (bar)
  server griddb_svr options (table_name 'loct2');
alter table foo set (autovacuum_enabled = 'false');
alter table bar set (autovacuum_enabled = 'false');
alter foreign table foo2 alter column f1 options (rowkey 'true');
alter foreign table bar2 alter column f1 options (rowkey 'true');
insert into foo values(1,1);
insert into foo values(3,3);
insert into foo2 values(2,2,2);
insert into foo2 values(4,4,4);
insert into bar values(1,11);
insert into bar values(2,22);
insert into bar values(6,66);
insert into bar2 values(3,33,33);
insert into bar2 values(4,44,44);
insert into bar2 values(7,77,77);
update bar set f2 = f2 + 100
from
  ( select f1 from foo union all select f1+3 from foo ) ss
where bar.f1 = ss.f1;
WARNING:  Fetched rowkey is not same as expected
```

ERROR:

```
GridDB-API is failed by 140037 at griddb_fdw.c: 2754
```

It may be related to the cursor pointing target. Please anyone help to fix the issue.